# How to display unique records in the result after left join in pentaho Data integraion

Tags: unique, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration, pdi

Table input [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NovId.png)

| ID | Code | Amt | PK | ALI |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE000A3MQYU1 | NFID | 10000 | 123 | jj |
| DE000A3MQYU1 | NFID | 234 | 124 | jj |

Another input [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxCTi.png)

| ID | Code | FK |
| --- | --- | --- |
| DE000A3MQYU1 | NFID | 1 |
| DE000A3MQYU1 | NFID | 2 |

Expected Result :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDIa0.png)

| ID | Code | Amt | PK | ALI | FK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE000A3MQYU1 | NFID | 10000 | 123 | jj | 1 |
| DE000A3MQYU1 | NFID | 234 | 124 | jj | 2 |

I tried stream lookup but it will give only either high or low value from another stream but  iam expecting below output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WP3O.png)

| ID | Code | Amt | PK | ALI | FK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| DE000A3MQYU1 | NFID | 10000 | 123 | jj | 1 |
| DE000A3MQYU1 | NFID | 234 | 124 | jj | 2 |

Comment: Please, don't use screenshots when you can add the tables properly formatted in your question. In the box where you write the question, at the top right, you have a question mark that expands the formatting options, there's one specific with examples for adding properly formatted tables. If we can see the tables with the question instead to navigating back and forth to look at the screenshots understanding the question is easier.

Comment: What is the logic to cross the data between your two input tables? Why PK 123 goes with FK 1 instead of with FK 2? If input Table1 should always have the same number of rows than input Table2 and both tables come properly sorted, you could add a sequence (there's a step in Pentaho to add a sequence to rows) to both tables and then use a Merge join using the sequence to do the join so you get your expected results.

Comment: Both tables will have same no of rows and using xml file to load the tables so like 1st row to lookup get 1st 123 to FK1 2nd row to 2nd value I will try your suggestion

Comment: Now I am facing issue because two tables are not having same data is there another solution for this

Comment: For your second issue better open a new question explaining better what you are getting and what the expected results are. If there is not logical key to join the two tables, just the order you read the data, and they don't have the same number of rows, explain what do you expect to do with the rows no matching.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly you are saying the first row of table A should connect to the first row of table B, and the second row of table A should connect to the second row of table B, etc.

Easiest way is to add a rownumber in your loading process for both tables and use stream lookup to connect on the rownumber.

This can be done in SQL load (for example table input) via rownumber() over() for Transact SQL, and for csv/text with the option rownum in oputput on the content tab of text input step. In case of SQL make sure your ordering is the same.

WARNING: Eitherway connecting up based on the order of a file or table is NEVER advised. It is always better to connect tables based on a PK and FK, or some other structured way of connecting data together which is not dependent on the order of rows/lines.